# Undefined index in Function and Confirm password is not working

Tags: php, forms, function

I'm converting my Form Validation code into function but problem is that it's giving error Undefined index of `$confirm` variable which is already define and also confirm password is not working.

**Function**

```
function formValidation($action,$confirm){
    $result = "";
    $input = $_POST[$action];
    $confirm = $_POST[$confirm];
    // For Email Validation
    $find = 'email';
    $path = $action;
    $pos = strpos($path,$find);
    if(empty(user_input($input))){
        $result = "$action is missing";
    }elseif($pos !== false){
        $email = filter_var($input, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
            $result = "Email invalid format";
        }

    }elseif($confirm !== $_POST['password']){
        $result = "password is not confirm";
    }
    return $result;
}
```

And there is any way I call function one time and it checkx all fields and return error

**Trigger**

```
$email_err = $password_err = $username_err = $confirmPWD_err = "";
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $email_err = formValidation('prd_email','');
    $password_err = formValidation('password','');
    $username_err = formValidation('username','');
    $confirmPWD_err = formValidation('password','confirm');
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="username" name="username" type="text" />
            <?php echo $username_err ?>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="email" name="prd_email" type="text" />
        <?php echo $email_err ?>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="password" name="password" type="password" />
        <?php echo $password_err ?>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password" name="confirm" type="password" />
        <?php echo $confirmPWD_err ?>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="submit" value="submit" />

</form>
```

Comment: Need to set default as null `formValidation($action=null,$confirm=null)`

Comment: does not work `function formValidation($action=null,$confirm=null){`

Comment: try this as well `elseif($confirm && $confirm !== $_POST['password'])` instead of `elseif($confirm !== $_POST['password'])`, this beside the `function formValidation($action,$confirm=null)`

Comment: or it could be `elseif(!empty($confirm) && $confirm !== $_POST['password'])`

Comment: yeah it's working but still giving Undefined Index error and when i give only password and left empty confirm password it's did not show empty error for confirm password. but it's checking fine password confirmation

Comment: if you have this `formValidation($action,$confirm=null)` and when you call the function ignore the second argument ($confirm) , except for password confirmation call, what do you get?, like  `$email_err = formValidation('prd_email',);` and `$username_err = formValidation('username');`

Comment: if i left these field blank it's shows error and if i pass data in it so it's work fine.

Comment: you have another use of `$confirm` without checking if it has value or not, change this `$confirm = $_POST[$confirm];` to this `if($confirm){$confirm = $_POST[$confirm];}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, is it working for you?

```
function formValidation($action,$confirm = null){
    $result = "";
    $input = $_POST[$action];
    if($confirm){$confirm = $_POST[$confirm];}
    // For Email Validation
    $find = 'email';
    $path = $action;
    $pos = strpos($path,$find);
    if(empty(user_input($input))){
        $result = "$action is missing";
    }elseif($pos !== false){
        $email = filter_var($input, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
            $result = "Email invalid format";
        }
    }elseif(!empty($confirm) && $confirm !== $_POST['password']){
        $result = "password is not confirm";
    }
    return $result;
}
```

And call the function like this

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $email_err = formValidation('prd_email');
  $password_err = formValidation('password');
  $username_err = formValidation('username');
  $confirmPWD_err = formValidation('password', 'confirm');
}
```